# Months differenece between two dates

Tags: vb.net

How can i get the proper format.

Lets say i have date from `21.03.2010` 
                date to   `21.05.2011`

My date difference should return something like this

```
Months / Years
    3/2010
    4/2010
    5/2010
    ...
    12/2010
    1/2011
    ...
    5/2011
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going:

```
Private Sub Button50_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button50.Click

    printDateRange(New Date(2010, 3, 21), New Date(2011, 5, 21))

End Sub

Private Sub printDateRange(startDate As Date, endDate As Date)

    Dim months As Integer = DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, startDate, endDate)

    For parser As Integer = 0 To months
        Dim newdate As Date = startDate.AddMonths(parser)
        Debug.Print(String.Format("{0}/{1}", newdate.Month, newdate.Year))
    Next

End Sub
```

You'll still need to add all the validation and error handling etc